# Ant Design Table component with editable rows and controlled inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd, react-state, controlled-component

I am trying to make a Table component with controlled inputs using Ant Design.

I started from Antd doc: [Table with editable rows](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-row) then 1) modularized the code 2) used Hooks and 3) removed the use of Antd Forms.

I have 4 components

- Table
- Cell
- InputNode
- Button

Inside the Table Component, I have 3 states:

- editing ==> When editing is set to TRUE, the row is editable and accepts user inputs
- currentRowValues ==> currentRowValues will hold the current user inputs of the editable row
- rowList ==> Once I press Save, the currentRowValues will populate the rowList

But when I press the edit icon for a given row:

- the InputNumber will lose the current value and will not change according to user input
- the DatePicker will hold the value but will not update according to user inputs

I would like to have InputNumber and DatePicker keep the initial value when the row is under edit state, reflects user inputs and update the row list when the user hit save.

I have tweaked the code many times but couldn't make it work

Here is the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-table-u5cet)

Answer (score 0):

To meet the specified requirements, you need to slightly change the code

1. When you click the edit button, you need to copy the values of the current row to currentRowValues

```
const editRow = (rowKey) => {
  setEditingKey(rowKey);
  setCurrentRowValues({ ...rowList.find((row) => row.key === rowKey) });
};
```

2. To change data, you need to transfer not only the value, but the name of the parameter

```
const handleInputChange = (value, dataIndex) => {
  setCurrentRowValues((old) => ({ ...old, [dataIndex]: value }));
};
```

3. You need to change the parameters passed to the InputNode component

```
<InputNode
  style={{ margin: 0 }}
  inputType={inputType}
  value={currentRowValues[dataIndex]}
  handleInputChange={(value) => {
    handleInputChange(value, dataIndex);
  }}
/>
```

4)For the correct storage of dates, you need to convert them to a string in the DatePicker component

```
<AntDatePicker
  picker="month"
  size="small"
  allowClear="true"
  placeholder={placeholder}
  format="YYYY-MM"
  value={value}
  onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e.format("MMM YYYY"))
  {...restProps}
/>
```

This is an old question, but I hope this will help those who will face a similar question in the future

Link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-table-forked-o7xyi?file=/src/index.js)